# How to align x-axis and y-axis in two pgfpots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have two pgfplots side-by-side that I want to align the x-axes horizontally, also if I put the two plots one on top of the other, I want to align the y-axes vertically. Here is the working example that I have. Manually specifiying the x- and y-shifts are cumbersome if the plots will change in length (and widths) in the future. A more elegant and understandable mechanism is needed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
 The impulse response of a linear time-invariant system is $$h(n) = \{1, \underset{\uparrow}{2}, 1, -1 \}$$
 Determine the response of the system to the input signal $$x(n) = \{\underset{\uparrow}{1}, 2, 3, 1 \}$$
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{axis}[axis x line=middle,
    x axis line style={thick},
    enlarge x limits,
    axis y line=middle,
    y axis line style={thick},ytick=\empty,
    tick style={draw=none},
    xlabel={$k$},
    ylabel={$x(k)$},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathparseFPU{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\else \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\fi},
    nodes near coords align=left,
    point meta = y,
    title={Plot of $x(k)$}
    ]
\addplot[ycomb, color=blue, mark=o, very thick] coordinates { (-2,0) (-1,0) (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,1) (4,0) (5,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{axis}[axis x line=middle,
    x axis line style={thick},
    enlarge x limits,
    axis y line=middle,
    y axis line style={thick},ytick=\empty,
    tick style={draw=none},
    xlabel={$k$},
    ylabel={$h(k)$},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathparseFPU{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\else \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\fi},
    nodes near coords align=left,
    point meta = y,
    title={Plot of $h(k)$}
    ]
\addplot[ycomb, color=green, mark=o, very thick] coordinates {(-3,0) (-2,0) (-1,1) (0,2) (1,1) (2,-1) (3,0) (4,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Example}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\begin{axis}[axis x line=middle,
    x axis line style={thick},
    enlarge x limits,
    axis y line=middle,
    y axis line style={thick},ytick=\empty,
    tick style={draw=none},
    xlabel={$k$},
    ylabel={$x(k)$},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathparseFPU{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\else \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\fi},
    nodes near coords align=left,
    point meta = y,
    title={Plot of $x(k)$},
    name = first
    ]
    \addplot[ycomb, color=blue, mark=o, very thick] coordinates { (-2,0) (-1,0) (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,1) (4,0) (5,0)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[axis x line=middle,
    x axis line style={thick},
    enlarge x limits,
    axis y line=middle,
    y axis line style={thick},ytick=\empty,
    tick style={draw=none},
    xlabel={$k$},
    ylabel={$h(k)$},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathparseFPU{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\else \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\fi},
    nodes near coords align=left,
    point meta = y,
    title={Plot of $h(k)$}
    at=(first.below south west), 
    anchor=north west,
    yshift = -1.5cm,
    name = second
    ]
\addplot[ycomb, color=green, mark=o, very thick] coordinates {(-3,0) (-2,-1) (-1,1) (0,2) (1,1) (2,0) (3,0) (4,0)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way is to use `groupplots`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\newcommand{\pgfmathparseFPU}[1]{\begingroup%
 \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
 \pgfmathparse{#1}%
 \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ReportVShift}[2][]{%
 \immediate\write\@auxout{\xdef\string\myshift#1{#2}}%
}
\makeatother 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
 The impulse response of a linear time-invariant system is \[h(n) = \{1,
 \underset{\uparrow}{2}, 1, -1 \}\]
 Determine the response of the system to the input signal \[x(n) =
 \{\underset{\uparrow}{1}, 2, 3, 1 \}\]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\ifcsname myshiftA\endcsname
\edef\myshift{\myshiftA}
\else
\edef\myshift{0pt}
\fi
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 1,horizontal sep=6mm},
    height=3.5cm,width=5.5cm,
    axis x line=middle,,
    x axis line style={thick},
    enlarge x limits,
    axis y line=middle,
    y axis line style={thick},ytick=\empty,
    tick style={draw=none},
    xlabel={$k$},    
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathparseFPU{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\else \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\fi},
    nodes near coords align=left,
    point meta = y]
\nextgroupplot[title={Plot of $x(k)$},ylabel={$x(k)$}]
\addplot[ycomb, color=blue, mark=o, very thick] coordinates { (-2,0) (-1,0) (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,1) (4,0) (5,0)};
\path (0,0) coordinate (OL);
%
\nextgroupplot[title={Plot of $h(k)$},ylabel={$h(k)$},yshift=\myshift]
\addplot[ycomb, color=green, mark=o, very thick] coordinates {(-3,0) (-2,0) (-1,1) (0,2) (1,1) (2,-1) (3,0) (4,0)};
\path (0,0) coordinate (OR) let \p1=($(OL)-(OR)$)
  in \pgfextra{\ReportVShift[A]{\y1}};
\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Example}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=1 by 2,vertical sep=6mm},
    height=3cm,height=3.5cm,width=7cm,
    axis x line=middle,
    x axis line style={thick},
    enlarge x limits,
    axis y line=middle,
    y axis line style={thick},ytick=\empty,
    tick style={draw=none},
    xlabel={$k$},    
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathparseFPU{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\else \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\fi},
    nodes near coords align=left,
    point meta = y]
\nextgroupplot[title={Plot of $x(k)$},ylabel={$x(k)$}]
    \addplot[ycomb, color=blue, mark=o, very thick] coordinates { (-2,0) (-1,0) (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,1) (4,0) (5,0)};
%
\nextgroupplot[title={Plot of $h(k)$},ylabel={$h(k)$}]
    \addplot[ycomb, color=green, mark=o, very thick] coordinates {(-3,0) (-2,-1) (-1,1) (0,2) (1,1) (2,0) (3,0) (4,0)};
\end{groupplot} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

However, I had to report the difference in y coordinates of the two axis origins to achieve alignment. Therefore, here are two alternatives in which you do not have to do such things: set the baseline appropriate and use a `matrix`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\newcommand{\pgfmathparseFPU}[1]{\begingroup%
 \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
 \pgfmathparse{#1}%
 \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% \usepackage{tikz}
% \usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows, positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}
 The impulse response of a linear time-invariant system is \[h(n) = \{1,
 \underset{\uparrow}{2}, 1, -1 \}\]
 Determine the response of the system to the input signal \[x(n) =
 \{\underset{\uparrow}{1}, 2, 3, 1 \}\]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(OL)}]
\begin{axis}[axis x line=middle,height=3.5cm,width=5.5cm,
    x axis line style={thick},
    enlarge x limits,
    axis y line=middle,
    y axis line style={thick},ytick=\empty,
    tick style={draw=none},
    xlabel={$k$},
    ylabel={$x(k)$},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathparseFPU{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\else \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\fi},
    nodes near coords align=left,
    point meta = y,
    title={Plot of $x(k)$}
    ]
\addplot[ycomb, color=blue, mark=o, very thick] coordinates { (-2,0) (-1,0) (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,1) (4,0) (5,0)};
\path (0,0) coordinate (OL);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\qquad
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(OR)}]
\begin{axis}[axis x line=middle,height=3.5cm,width=5.5cm,
    x axis line style={thick},
    enlarge x limits,
    axis y line=middle,
    y axis line style={thick},ytick=\empty,
    tick style={draw=none},
    xlabel={$k$},
    ylabel={$h(k)$},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathparseFPU{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\else \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\fi},
    nodes near coords align=left,
    point meta = y,
    title={Plot of $h(k)$}
    ]
\addplot[ycomb, color=green, mark=o, very thick] coordinates {(-3,0) (-2,0) (-1,1) (0,2) (1,1) (2,-1) (3,0) (4,0)};
\path (0,0) coordinate (OR);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}    
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Example}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix{
\begin{axis}[axis x line=middle,height=3.5cm,width=7cm,
    x axis line style={thick},
    enlarge x limits,
    axis y line=middle,
    y axis line style={thick},ytick=\empty,
    tick style={draw=none},
    xlabel={$k$},
    ylabel={$x(k)$},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathparseFPU{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\else \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\fi},
    nodes near coords align=left,
    point meta = y,
    title={Plot of $x(k)$},
    name = first
    ]
    \addplot[ycomb, color=blue, mark=o, very thick] coordinates { (-2,0) (-1,0) (0,1) (1,2) (2,3) (3,1) (4,0) (5,0)};
\end{axis}\\

\begin{axis}[axis x line=middle,height=3.5cm,width=7cm,
    x axis line style={thick},
    enlarge x limits,
    axis y line=middle,
    y axis line style={thick},ytick=\empty,
    tick style={draw=none},
    xlabel={$k$},
    ylabel={$h(k)$},
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathparseFPU{\pgfplotspointmeta}%
    \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt\else \pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\fi},
    nodes near coords align=left,
    point meta = y,
    title={Plot of $h(k)$}
    at=(first.below south west), 
    anchor=north west,
    yshift = -1.5cm,
    name = second
    ]
\addplot[ycomb, color=green, mark=o, very thick] coordinates {(-3,0) (-2,-1) (-1,1) (0,2) (1,1) (2,0) (3,0) (4,0)};
\path (0,0) coordinate (OR);
\end{axis} \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW, do not use the `scale` key, but set the `height` and `width` appropriately. This approach is certainly not better than `groupplots`.

Comment: Thanks, I opted to use the matrix{ } scheme, which is simpler. In the second frame the y-axis is still not aligned, so I just edited the plot. I removed one zero on the left, and added one on the right: \addplot[ycomb, color=green, mark=o, very thick] coordinates {(-2,-1) (-1,1) (0,2) (1,1) (2,0) (3,0) (4,0) (5,0)};. And I think that did the trick, y-axes are now aligned.